# How to execute external exe on table insert?

Tags: windows, sql-server

I want to create an executable that would be triggered by Sql Server when a row is inserted into a certain table. Does Sql Server offer any sort of hooks that would do something like that? If so, where would I find documentation or a tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing which version of SQL server would be helpful.

You'll want to have a look at [triggers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx).  In this particular instance, you'll use a trigger to call a stored procedure, which will then call your executable.

Keep in mind that it's pretty easy to get sideways with triggers in terms of both [security](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191134.aspx) and that certain triggers can fire when ANY valid event occurs (and not necessarily row changes occur).

Comment: Yeah, as for version, I'm not sure what's installed as I don't maintain the DB. But I'll look into this solution. Thanks!